# How to Dynamically Add Elements in Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to dynamically add elements in Vue. I tried using the V-for as a for loop, however, the output is just the second item in the array. My goal is to create a new box for each of the array items.

The first block is my script code containing my two arrays. The second block is the template or HTML. I tried to loop through each of the numbs array and create a new box in each instance, however, I am having trouble creating new boxes for each element in the array.

```js
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      numbs: ['Application 1', 'Application 2'],
      applications: [
        { ver: '0.99911', status: 'Ready for Sale', deploymentD: '09/10/2020', deploymentC: 'XXXX'},
        { ver: '0.99911', status: 'Ready for Sale', deploymentD: '09/10/2020', deploymentC: 'XXXX'}

      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
<div class="body">

  <div class="box"
  v-for="(demo, index) in numbs"
  :key="index">
    <div class="heading">
      {{demo}}
    </div>
    <button class="info"><router-link to = "/viewapp">View</router-link></button>
    <button class="edit"><router-link to = "/editapp">Edit</router-link></button>
    <img class ="place" src="../images/imageinsert.jpg" />
    <div class ="summary" 
      v-for="(apps, index) of applications"
      :key="index">
      Application Version {{apps.ver}}
      {{apps.status}}, {{apps.deploymentD}}, {{apps.deploymentC}}
    </div>
    </div>

   
</div>
</template>
```

[Here is an image of how the code currently runs. It prints out the last element of both arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sChRc.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

To loop through an array and create an element for each item, you use the `v-for` directive. You use it like so:

```
<div class="summary" v-for="(apps, index) in applications" :key="index">
   Application Version {{apps.ver}}
   {{apps.status}}, {{apps.deploymentD}}, {{apps.deploymentC}}
</div>
```

You have `v-for=(apps, index) for applications"` (it should be `in` not `for`)

**Also**, you are using the `index` variable in both the inner and outer `for` loops. That's bound to cause an issue.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that mistake! I main issue is creating new box divs for each element in the array. I tried to run the for loop in that div, but I'm not sure why it isn't creating a new box for each of the values in the numb array.

Comment: @sptech updated my answer. You are using the index variable for 2 different things.